# Prevent Time machine backups from freezing a movie that's playing (from the same disk as time capsule)

Tags: time-machine, time-capsule

I have Time machine backing up every hour, so it will run inevitably at least once while I'm watching a *(totally legally downloaded)* movie, which I happen to store in the same external drive as the time capsule, so when it's backing up the reproduction has some hiccups that mess all the video compression for a couple of seconds.
Can I prevent this in an automatic way which doesn't involve manually skipping backups or turning it off every time I watch a movie?

Comment: you can set your backup to occur every 4,6,8 hours or something like that to improve your chances of it not happening during a movie.

Comment: There is a third party spp that expands the settings you can apply to when the time capsule backs up... can’t think of the name yet...